# How to deal with the error: Unbound module Sys_unix

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I've encountered the error Unbound module Sys_unix`.

The code in `utop` is:

```
utop # #require "core_unix";;
utop # open Core;;
utop # open Core_unix;;
utop # open Sys;;
utop # open Core_unix.Sys_unix;;
Error: Unbound module Core_unix.Sys_unix
utop # Sys.readdir "/Users/";;
Line 1, characters 0-11:
Alert deprecated: Core.Sys.readdir
[since 2021-04] Use [Sys_unix]
Line 1, characters 0-11:
Alert deprecated: Core.Sys.readdir
[since 2021-04] Use [Sys_unix]
- : [ `Use_Sys_unix ] = `Use_Sys_unix
utop # Sys_unix.readdir;;
Error: Unbound module Sys_unix
```

I don't know why and I can't even find a documentation about module `Sys_unix`.

Comment: How do you know there is a `Sys_unix` module if you don't have any documentation for it?

Comment: Because `[since 2021-04] Use [Sys_unix]`. I know there is a Sys.readdir. This is an experiment I did in the terminal and I actually wrote the code in VSCode, which reminds me that Sys.readdir is deprecated.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read that closely apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the documentation: https://ocaml.org/p/core_unix/v0.15.0/doc/Sys_unix/index.html

The module seems to be in the *library* `core_unix.sys_unix`, which is in the *package* `core_unix`.

I would expect this to work, assuming you have installed the package:

```
#require "core_unix.sys_unix";;
open Sys_unix;;
```