# Stdlib.Filename.extension error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type int

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

```
let get_path_elts path = 
  let rec walk_dir dirs = 
    match dirs with
    | [] -> []
    | dir::tail -> 
      match (stat dir).st_kind with
      | S_REG -> if Stdlib.Filename.extension dir = "ml" || Stdlib.Filename.extension dir = "mli" then dir::(walk_dir tail) else walk_dir tail
      | S_DIR -> List.concat [walk_dir (Array.to_list (Sys_unix.readdir dir)); (walk_dir tail)]
      | _ -> walk_dir tail
  in walk_dir [path]
;;
```

This is my code and I pasted it into utop. But it reports error:

```
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

This code is originally in a file in vscode but there's no error there. Wonder why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `core`, which I know you use because of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74059218/how-to-deal-with-the-error-unbound-module-sys-unix), `=` is defined as `int -> int -> bool`.

You need to use the string-specific equality operator, which you can bring into scope by locally opening `String` just for the predicate, for example:

```
String.(Stdlib.Filename.extension dir = "ml")
```